# Can we get windows user details in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am adding a webchat(connected to bot framework) as extension in google chrome. I need to capture windows user details by javascript.

Comment: An extension can invoke an external utility via nativeMessaging API, which can get the user details and send back to an extension. For more details see the documentation and google up the existing extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there's no API that can do it. You're welcome to [see the list](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) yourself.

There are 2 ideas that come close:

1. [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) can provide you the details of the Google user if the user is signed into Chrome - if you just need some sort of identifier. You'd need `"identity"` and `"identity.email"` permissions and would need to call [`chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo). Interestingly, that produces no permission warnings.
2. [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/native_messaging) allows you to create a Windows binary that your extension can talk to. Obviously, a native application can do whatever, including getting the signed-in user details, but that requires users to install another component from outside Web Store. In short: it's a big hammer that's likely not worth it for just this.